# Debian cannot set scale of 1 monitor to 200% - must be identical

Tags: debian, gnome

I am running GNOME on Debian bookworm with 3 displays.
Primary display is 1920x1200 and the other two are 1280x1024.

When I try to change the primary display to a scale of 200% (default is 100%), it says it is not possible due to hardware limitations. The other displays do not even have the scaling options present. The error in journalctl is

```
gnome-control-c[5038]: Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Logical monitor scales must be identical
```

Is there any way I can deal with this or bypass this safeguard?

Comment: you can't bypass "hardware limitations."

Comment: I am able to make adjustments with xrandr and the 2x2 scale property, but am not sure how to calibrate the other 2 displays properly.

Comment: Okay I made it work with xrandr commands (set first display to 2x2 scale, then adjust the other displays' position and scale to match, in my case I had to upgrade the other two displays to 4x4 scale to compensate). HOWEVER, performance seems to be impacted in terms of rendering speed. I wonder why.